# S3 lifecycle policy directories

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to set a S3 lifecycle policy.

I have bucket with several objects like:

- `MYBUCKET/file1/.trash/`
- `MYBUCKET/file2/.trash/`
- `MYBUCKET/file3/.trash/`

I have set a life cycle policy with prefix `/file1/.trash` it works but I want to set for all of them like `*/.trash/` did not work. Any idea how can I set the right prefix?

Comment: The Lifecycle policy [filter element](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html#intro-lifecycle-rules-filter) does not support wildcards, so you must specify one filter per prefix you want to filter on.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, for a very simple reason: S3 is not a filesystem: is a flat object repository disguised as a filesystem.
Folders in S3 does not exists: every object you upload, is registered with three base values:

- The object **content**
- The **bucket** where the object is stored
- The object **key**, which contains what you see as the path, but in fact is a string that contains all the path plus the file name

If you upload an "hello.jpeg" under the bucket "hello-world" in us-east-1, in the subfolder "img", your object is stored as:

- The content of the image
- The reference (ARN) to the bucket, ***arn:aws:s3:::hello-world***
- The key of the object, ***img/hello.jpeg***

Thinking in these terms, where the object path + filename is just a string that can contain virtually anything, you can understand easily why a "folder filter" on a policy on S3 is not thinkable.
This is also why if you want a complete serverless filesystem on AWS the righe choice is EFS and not S3.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-arn-format.html